# Rails Square API - `Authorization` http header of your request was malformed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, http-headers, square

I am building a Rails 5 app that submits a payment to square.

I have a form that post register info to my DB then calculates amounts to be charged to credit card.

I am using the Square SqPaymentForm found in the [Payment Forms doc](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/sqpaymentform/sqpaymentform-overview).
When I attempt to process the CC I am receiving an error saying malformated authorization token.

I am not sure how to even pass an authorization token and all the documents and example code I look at dose not indicate that I need to configure any header model, method, etc..

Any help or advice is welcomed please keep in mind that this is my first attempt to link a ROR ap to a third party API. Here is my [Git](https://github.com/KKM-Clients/ROAR-Rails/tree/square) to view my code.

Comment: Have you set the `access_token` anywhere? See example here: https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v2/rails_payment . Most notably, take a look at `config` > `application.rb` to see how it's being set. For reference of authorization headers, see: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#requestandresponseheaders

Comment: yes. I have it set in my application.rb using figaro for env. I have spoken with square about this error and I have it working now.